How to get warning details when importing FBX with a script?
I'm trying to get the warnings details of an import FBX (like missing textures...)
I'm using this method :
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=input_fbx_path)
I can see the results I want in the info pannel of Blender, but I can't make a script that copy those infos and put them in a file. Is that even possible ?
I successfully got the screen area and space, but then, what can I do to automatically copy this ?
Or am I going the wrong way and is there a much simpler method to get those warnings log into a file ?

You should have a look at the fbx importer's code. That's what makes the the warnings, so that will probably answer your question. It's a lot of code there... I am not sure you will find many people here who will be happy to do that job for you... But maybe I am wrong...
